# Python2 vs Python3 - parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, mqtt

I try to read MQTT messages using Python. For debugging purposes, I reduced the program at the minimum.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with code  " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("temperature")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    if message.topic == "temperature":
        print("New message received")        
        dhtreadings_json = json.loads(message.payload)
        temperature = dhtreadings_json['temperature']
        print(temperature)

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.username_pw_set("user","password")                  
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.connect("192.168.1.133",1883,60)
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Under Python 2, everything works fine:

[image: Output in Python2]

Under Python3, I got the connection established message and I am informed that a new message was received and this is all. More than this no other output after:

[image: Output in Python3]

Environment: Latest version of Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3B+

As suggested, I replaced to print ("New message received", message.payload).
The message.payload is the same in Python2 and Python3.

Python2:

[image: Print message.payload in Python2]

Python3:

[image: Print message.payload in Python3]

Thank you!

Comment: What does `print(message.payload)` give you?

Comment: Yep, change this line print("New message received") to print("New message received", message.payload) and post the output

Comment: @Tomalak @ Alex K As suggested, I replaced to print ("New message received", message.payload).
The message.payload is the same in Python2 and Python3.

Comment: I still suspect that there is an exception being thrown. Put the `json.loads()` into a `try:`/`except:` block and print any exception.

Comment: Tomalak is right. `on_message` is called [in a try-except, and any exceptions are logged and discarded](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L2907-L2910).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be because with Python3 the `message.payload` is a byte array and with Python2 it's a string. (this can be seen in the images you posted because the Python3 strings are proceeded with `b'...`)

The change is to move closer to the MQTT spec which treats all MQTT payloads as just a collection bytes and also not making any assumptions about what character set should be used to covert the payload to a string.

The following should work with Python3 (assuming the initial json is utf-8 encoded)

```
dhtreadings_json = json.loads(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thank you!
Your solution worked perfectly in Python2 and Python3, as well!